# Posting Json data using WebClient to WebAPI shows parameter as Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post the Json data of content length around 351383(Array length of 2062) but on posting the request from WEBCLIENT to Web API Controller; the controller receives parameter as Null.

Whereas on Sending 800 records to Web API Controller it does receive the proper Json data. So this seems to be as some data/ content length restriction issue.

So I tried adding below all options but none worked.

1)

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="36000" />
```

2)

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

3)

```
 <system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
     <webServices>
         <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000"></jsonSerialization>
     </webServices>
   </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
```

4)

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="451383"/>
```

Please let me know if anything apart from these options that I should try to make it work. The Method of Posting through `WebClient` I am using is as below :

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Clear();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.UploadStringCompleted += (data, exception) =>
    {
        if (exception.Error == null) return;
    };
    client.UploadStringAsync(
    new Uri('apiurl')),
    jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Where you have added those config changes - is it on webclient side or  WebAPI side?

Comment: I have added those config at WebAPI Side, and the web client side is Console application

Comment: Can you provide your Web API code?